# key listeners without focusing app's window

Tags: java, focus, jna, keystrokes

I'm trying to make an app using java that depends on keystrokes mainly, the problem I encountered is that the focus should be on the frame/component of my app to achieve its functionality  , but I need it to work in background without requiring the app to be focused on .
Is there any way to achieve that rather than using JNA ?

Comment: There is the KeyboardFocusManager and the KeyEventDispatcher - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/KeyEventDispatcher.html. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @user1291492 , nope , I was looking for something that overcomes the focusing issue automatically , without my interference , but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson something close to that , any ideas ?

Comment: *"something close to that , any ideas ?"*  Here's one.  Use your powers, ..for **good.**